# Is there a package format for packing source code files, that provide end-users an easy and straight-forward option to compile (& install) the program

Tags: open-source, github

For example in addition "Open" action, "Compile & Install" be another available action when user click on package

Comment: A straight-forward user-friendly package is an EXE file.

Comment: It depends on what operating system(s) you are targeting, what programming language(s) you are using, and what build system(s) you are using. It also depends on whether you expect your users to already have the toolchain your source code needs to compile. There are so many different possibilities, that there is no single correct answer to your question.

Comment: @immibis I mean packing of open source files and leaving compilation to end users

Comment: @clement-cherlin suppose OS is linux, select one language yourself for answering. and the toolchain should be installed them-self by the compile option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are just too many languages and operating systems for a single package format to be viable.

- before the explosion of package managers, there was the expectation that `./configure && make && sudo make install` would do the right thing
- there are tons of build-system or package-manager specific approaches

  - Homebrew's formulas and Arch's PKGBUILD files are a fairly generic approach at capturing compilation and installation info
- container images are currently one of the best options to provide an “it just works” compilation toolchain

  - with techniques like AppImage, the image can be a self-contained executable on the host system – no dependencies on Docker etc

But all of these solutions make assumptions about the host environment, for example that the user will be using Linux or has certain tools installed.

The only truly generic package format is an archive that provides installation instructions in a README or INSTALL file.